# Performance comparison between http and https Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, ssl, https

I am trying to do a performance benchmark between the usage of http and https in a SpringBoot application.

I have created a simple springboot Application with an Entity:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TABLE")
public class User {
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "USER_SALARY", nullable = true, length = 10)
    private int salary;

    protected User() {
    }
}
```

A controller:

```java
@Data
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/one/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(
            @PathVariable("userId") int userId) {
        return userService.getUser(userId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody()
    public User addNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return this.userService.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

A service, where I added logs that permit me to see execution time of `getAllUsers()` method.

```java
@Data
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<User> findAll = this.usersDao.findAll();

        long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        log.info("Execution Time log: {} ms", executionTime);

        return findAll;
    }

    public User addUser(User user) {
        return this.userDao.save(user);
    }

    public User getUser(Integer id) { return this.userDao.findById(id).get();}
}
```

A Dao:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

`HttpServer` class, that permit me using `application.properties`, to run Tomcat server on http (8091) and https (8443), as the following:

```java
@Component
public class HttpServer {
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(@Value("${server.http.port}") int httpPort) {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setPort(httpPort);

        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
        return tomcat;
    }
}
```

`application.properties`

```
server.port=8443
server.http.port=8091

# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks

# The password used to generate the store certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=azerty

# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-password=azerty

# The format used for the keystore. It could be set to JKS in case it is a JKS file
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS


# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=analytics-certificate

# Spring Security enabled application accept only HTTPS requests
security.require-ssl=true
```

The certificate is auto-signed.
I have ommited other classes and methods for brevity.
The problem is that execution time is very low (between 4ms and 9ms) to make a comparison between http and https.
Which modification can I make, so I can have a relevant benchmark.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by execution is very low? Is this very fast or very slow? 4ms to 9ms is not that must slow as you are performing DB operation. If you need better performance for test, then try to use in memory DB like H2.

Comment: Yes, it's very fast, and execution time is very low. I am expecting high exection time to compare performance between http and https. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need slow performance. Instead you can increase load (total request per second) and then compare result. This will give you more accurate result than putting some false delay. You can use JMeter, really cool tool.

Comment: That's a very good idea. Now I am using Insomnia/Postman to do the tests, do you know how can I increase load please using bash or something else ?

Comment: Use JMeter. Configure you request and no of request per second. https://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Here is an example https://www.guru99.com/jmeter-performance-testing.html